# Does use of swift array automatically entangling use of NSArray?

Tags: arrays, performance, swift, nsarray

If one uses a swift array, is NSArray actively involved behind the scenes?

To demonstrate it seems to be, placing this in a SingleViewController:

```
var _board:[[Int]] = []
let numRows = 12
let numColumns = 11

func setupBoard() {
    for r in 0..<numRows {
        var boardRow:[Int] = []
        for c in 0..<numColumns {
            var one = 1
            boardRow.append(one)
        }
        _board.append(boardRow)
    }
}

func scramble() {
    let randomRow = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(numRows)))
    let randomColumn = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(numColumns)))
    let someValue = randomRow * numRows + randomColumn
    _board[randomRow][randomColumn] = someValue

}
```

and then in viewDidLoad,

```
setupBoard()

let startTime = NSDate()

println("Start")
for i in 0...2000 {
    scramble()
}

let stopTime = NSDate();
let interval = stopTime.timeIntervalSinceDate(startTime)
println("Done took:  \(interval)")
```

Aftr the Start message is in the console, pause execution.
It make take more then one attempt but one will see something like:

[image: Thread contents with convertArrayToNSArray]

Why?  Underlying motive is determine why placing values into the array takes a lot longer than expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to guess that it's because:

- This is all taking place in a class exposed to Objective-C; i.e. it inherits from NSObject, or you have called `@objc` on it (I can see that you have, in fact); and
- You are using Int, which *might* be sent to Objective-C but can't be (you can't have an NSArray of integers, as they are not objects), and therefore it makes more sense to convert it to NSNumber *now* rather than later. If you expand the missing call stack you'll see that the conversion to NSNumber is taking place. That is probably the cause of a great deal of inefficiency here.

Try the same thing in an Array in an isolated class (private, no inheritance from NSObject or exposure to Objective-C) and use an unbridgeable element type (e.g. a Struct you define in Swift).

Comment: !!  Refactored the example to move the array into a simple swift class of its own.  That improved performance issue.  I then went to the original code that inspired this.  Refactored it, moving array out from the SKScene based class to its own swift class.   An update that was taking 9 seconds is now taking 0.06 seconds!  150 times faster.  Instead of seconds per frame, now getting frames per second.    Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The Swift array is interchangeable with NSArray. When the array is used as a Swift array, it is treated as such, if it needs to be an NSArray, it is treated as that.

However, they use an efficient method to change between the two different types that shouldn't be causing you any performance problems.

You can hear Apple talking about how they convert back and forth in the [Swift Interoperability In Depth Video](http://devstreaming.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/407xxptt888z5jv/407/407_sd_swift_interoperability_in_depth.mov?dl=1). They talk about it starting at around 35:33.

Comment: Thanks.   Very interesting.  Entangled would be the wrong term.  Behind the scenes, a swift array really has both a swift version and an NSArray version.   matt's suggestion on moving the array into an isolated class resolves the performance issue.